# Official example on AWS documentation on how to add a service principal on a resource based policy does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-secrets-manager

I several `lambda` functions on my account to be able to access a secret.

(I cannot use identity policies, don't ask why)

I am following [this](https://ibb.co/d6jZQT4) example from the official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/auth-and-access_examples.html) so I am creating this resource based policy

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:sourceArn": "arn:aws:lambda::1234567891911:*"
        },
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:sourceAccount": "1234567891911"
        }
      }

    }
  ]
}
```

My `lambda` invocation fails as follows:

> "An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetSecretValue operation: User: arn:aws:sts::1234567891911:assumed-role/my-secret-name/my-lambda-name is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on resource: ps-shield-token because no identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action",

????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the problem.  Your policy example is valid for services that support [service-linked roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html#iam-term-service-linked-role)<sup>1</sup>.  Lambda functions [do not support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html) service-linked roles.  Therefore, the policy example is not valid for Lambda.

---

Service-linked roles, which are AWS-managed, are referenced by service name in resource-based policies, as in the OP.  For instance, the principal  `{ “Service”: “elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com” }` refers to the AWS-managed [ELB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/elb-service-linked-roles.html)  service-linked-role, which is called `AWSServiceRoleForElasticLoadBalancing`.  Again, there's no equivalent `lambda.amazon.aws` option here, because Lambda has no service-linked role<sup>2</sup>.

Functions have user-managed execution roles.  Execution roles (EC2 Instances and ECS Tasks have something similar) are referenced by the role ARN in the resource-based policy `"Principal": { AWS: <Lambda Role Arn> }`, as in @jellycsc's answer.

---

1. Although the docs could definitely be clearer, your [Example: Service principal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/auth-and-access_examples.html#auth-and-access_service) does refer to just to service-linked roles.  The first link on the page, [AWS Service Principal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html#principal-services), refers to "service principal" as used "services that support service-linked roles".
2. Lambda@Edge [does support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-permissions.html#using-service-linked-roles) service-linked roles.

Comment: This answer seems to confuse service principals with service-linked roles.  These are two totally different concepts.  You are correct that Lambda has no SLR, but that's not the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the lambda service that's getting the secret value. The lambda service first assumes the execution role which you set in your lambda function, and the execution role is the principle of the `secretsmanager:GetSecretValue` action. Therefore, the following policy should work.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement":
    [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal":
            {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567891911:role/<lambda-execution-role-name>"
            },
            "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes but I want to use a service as the principal in the resource policy.. In particular the lambda service. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think so. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: But the example I cited shows that this is possible

Comment: Yes, it is possible to give a service principal permission to retrieve your Secret.  But Lambda doesn't try to use its own (service principal) credentials to retrieve Secrets; only your Function, which uses credentials for your Execution Role, attempts to retrieve your Secret.